# "Suspect someone" VS "Be suspicious of someone"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, verbs

I was wondering whether the words "[suspect](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/suspect)" as a transitive verbs and the phrasal verb "be [suspicious](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/suspicious) of..." mean the same or not.

Example:

> 1- No one knows who killed her, but police suspect Sam. 
> 2- No one knows who killed her, but police are suspicious of Sam.

To me they both mean the same thing. If I am mistaken, please let me know about their nuance.

PS. Unfortunately, I did not find the [similar thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103700/suspect-versus-suspicious-as-adjectives) quite helpful.

Comment: More likely, the *victim* would have been suspicious of Sam. Saying that of the police makes me think that Sam might steal their lunch boxes. If you are [**suspicious**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/suspicious) of someone, you distrust them.

Comment: May I ask you to elaborate on your point @WeatherVane?

Comment: The police think Sam committed the crime, so they **suspect** him. If they think he *might* do something wrong, they are **suspicious** of him.

Comment: Does [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103655/to-suspect-vs-to-be-suspicious-of) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you very much @WeatherVane. I think I got the point. The key factor is that the amount of doubt involved in any case. If there is a 50/50 possibility, you are suspicious of..., while if you are positive or think that a wrong doing is almost certainly true, then you suspect. Do you confirm my take on your statements?

Comment: No, it's not about degree of possibility: Sam is on a list of suspects at the police station who could have committed the crime: they **suspect** him. But the police might be **suspicious** of someone who has not done anything wrong, but are 100% certain that it is only a matter of time before it happens. Or a 1% percent possibility: they just don't trust him. Or they might see someone coming out of the back door of a bank and are suspicious, but no crime is yet known to have been committed, so there is nothing to suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context here only

> No one knows who killed her, but police suspect Sam.

is correct. It means that the police have some evidence against Sam or some other reason to suspect him/her but perhaps not yet enough to arrest or bring a formal charge. Members of the general public might be suspicious of Sam as they do not trust them to behave legally but that is not the same as being a suspect.

Answer (score 2):

*Suspicious* is an attitude: the way you feel toward somebody. It may have no objective grounds at all, and needn't be tied to any particular event - indeed, there may not have been any relevant event at all.

*Suspect* (a person) is a verb, meaning something like "consider or hold the possibility that the person is responsible for a particular act that has happened, or a class of act that may happen".